# Select fields based on aggregates results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a typical `products` table with the fields `name` and `price`. I have to select the sum of all the prices, the **name** of the cheapest product and the **name**  of the most expensive product and then return it all in the same result set. I've tried some combinations but the best I could come up with was an ugly query with multiple nested subselects. Can anyone help me with a good query example, please? Thanks in advance.

To illustrate the problem, here is a minimalistic `products` table:

```
+----+-------+------------------+
| id | price | name             |
+----+-------+------------------+
|  1 |  2.20 | Shack Beer       |
|  2 |  3.40 | Freeze IPA       |
|  3 |  1.10 | Poor Man's Ale   |
|  4 |  3.40 | Alabama Sour     |
|  5 |  7.20 | Irish Stout      |
+----+-------+------------------+
```

Given the table above, the query must return the following result set:

```
          total_pricing = 17.30
       cheapest_product = Poor Man's Ale
 most_expensive_product = Irish Stout
```

Comment: Just want to ask what would happen if you have more than 1 cheapest/most expensive product?

Comment: I ran into this thought but I didn't include this constraint in the example. Thanks for your insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of options for you ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd5b0/13/1)):

```
SELECT SUM(p.price) AS total_pricing,
(
   SELECT name
   FROM products
   ORDER BY price 
   LIMIT 1
)AS cheapest_product,
(
   SELECT name
   FROM products
   ORDER BY price DESC
   LIMIT 1
)AS most_expensive_product
FROM products p;
```

Or in separate rows:

```
SELECT 'total_pricing' as Category, SUM(p.price) AS total_pricing
FROM products p
UNION
(
  SELECT 'cheapest_product', name
  FROM products
  ORDER BY price 
  LIMIT 1
)
UNION
(
  SELECT 'most_expensive_product', name
  FROM products
  ORDER BY price DESC
  LIMIT 1
);
```

Comment: It achieves the goal, but it relies on ORDER BY for such, what I think not to be much semantic, but I think it may be the clearest resolution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Check [**<kbd>SQL Fiddle</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b06e/2)

```
SELECT DISTINCT price,
                name
FROM products AS p1,

  (SELECT MAX(price) AS `most_expensive_product`,
          MIN(price) AS `cheapest_product`
   FROM products) AS p2
WHERE p2.most_expensive_product = p1.price
  OR p2.cheapest_product = p1.price
UNION
SELECT sum(price) AS price,
       "Total_pricing" AS name
FROM products;
```

Comment: The query returns the price along with the names and it's spawn across three rows. I didn't specify it very well in the question. My bad. I learned something new from your SQL by the way. Thanks a lot for your answer!